# Is it possible to make a bash script to simplify using echo to overwrite the same text file with new text?

Tags: linux, bash, echo

What I'm trying to do is simplify using `echo` as I will be overwriting the same file each time with different text.

Currently I'm using this in the terminal:

```
echo "blah blah blah blah" > /home/spaz/Documents/folder1/folder2/filename.txt
```

and I'd like to shorten that to something like:

```
customcommand blah blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is create an alias and use that to overwrite your file. Based on your question you could set the alias as:

```
alias customcommand='echo > /home/spaz/Documents/folder1/folder2/filename.txt'
```

Then when you want to pass text into the file you would use the following:

```
customcommand blah blah blah blah
```

Comment: Amazingly simple and works like a charm. Thank you very much.